# Help needed with InOrder iterator implementation for a tree

Tags: c++, tree, iterator, inorder

I'm implementing an InOrder iterator for a homework assignment, which means the iterator advances thus:

- Visit Left Child
- Visit Node
- Visit Right Child

There are also these complexity limitations:
Traversing over the entire tree should be of run-time complexity o(n) where n is the number of nodes in the tree and memory complexity of o(h) where h is the height of the tree.

I've tried using this method for implementing the advance(++) operator:

```
Tree<DataT>::_InOrderIterator::operator++()
{
    TreeNode* node = this->Node->GetRightChild();
    while(node != NULL)
    {
        advanceStack.Push(node);
        node = node->GetLeftChild();
    }
    node = advanceStack.Pop();
    if (node == NULL)
    {
        node = end; //reserved end node
    }
    this->Node = node;
    return *this;
}
```

I haven't got to testing it but I think it should work fine. My problems began when I was trying to implement the recede (--) operator. My initial approach was to have a second stack: recedeStack and use it in the same way I used it for the ++ operator. 
But I couldn't figure out how to keep the recede stack synched in the ++ operator and visa versa (the advanceStack in the -- operator). Not without overstepping the memory complexity limitation anyway.

Any ideas on how o solve this problem (with my current implementation or without)?

Comment: The memory constraint should give you a hughe clue: make it recursive. Draw a tree and picture subtrees. Then you'll see what the recursion should be based on

Comment: @sehe:I actually did just that, and that's how I got to the first solution. The use of a stack is to avoid recursion because it is a major problem to keep the state otherwise between calls to ++ operator. I guess I'm just not seeing how to update the recede data while advancing

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to manually implement the recursive algorithm (using stack) just write it recursive. much easier and comprehend-able. And it's as simple as visit left, node, right.
(since it's homework I won't go into more details).

Comment: I think you missed my actual problem. As commented above, I need to implement an iterator, not only traversing over the entire tree and thus I resorted to stack use.. But my actual difficulties are with implementing the -- and ++ operators concurrently.

Comment: @eladidan, Try to save each node's successor when you insert it, save its pointer just like you save its parent. Then implementing ++ should be easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //......    
       class Iterator{
              friend class BST<T>;
              stack<Node<T>*> stack;
              bool goLeft;
              Iterator(Node<T> *root):goLeft(true)
              {
                  stack.push(NULL);
                  stack.push(root);
              }
        public:

          const T &next()
            {
                Node<T> *curr = stack.top();
                if(curr == NULL) throw exception("The tree is empty");
                if(goLeft){
                    while(curr->left){
                        stack.push(curr->left);
                        curr = curr->left;
                    }
                    goLeft =false;
                }
                stack.pop();
                if(curr->right)
                {
                    stack.push(curr->right);
                    goLeft = true;
                }
                return curr->value;
            }


        };
//...
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar question on an interview and could find a solution. To traverse using recursion is simple. To write an iterator for breadth-first traverse is simple. But write an iterator for inorder traverse was for me a brain teaser. So after some research on the Net I've found a good solution among others that too verbose and relatively complicate. My language is C# but I hope it wouldn't be hard to translate it into any other one. BinaryTreeNode class has Data, Left, Right properties and is omitted here.

```
    public class BinaryTreeInorderIterator
    {
        #region Constructors

        public BinaryTreeInorderIterator(BinaryTreeNode aRoot)
        {
            Current = aRoot;

            if (Current == null)
            {
                // The tree is empty.
                return;
            }

            // Push the terminator.
            mNodeStack.Push(null);

            // To initialize inorder iterator go deep to the leftmost node of the left subtree 
            // of the root node along the way pushing nodes traversed so far.
            while (Current.Left != null)
            {
                mNodeStack.Push(Current);
                Current = Current.Left;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Public properties

        public BinaryTreeNode Current { get; private set; }

        #endregion

        #region Public methods

        public bool Next()
        {
            if (Current == null)
            {
                // Iterating finished already.
                return false;
            }

            if (Current.Right != null)
            {
                // There is right subtree.
                // Go deep to the leftmost node of the left subtree 
                // of the current node along the way pushing nodes traversed so far.
                Current = Current.Right;
                while (Current.Left != null)
                {
                    mNodeStack.Push(Current);
                    Current = Current.Left;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // There is no right subtree.
                // Go a level up.
                Current = mNodeStack.Pop();
            }

            return HasNext();
        }

        public bool HasNext()
        {
            return Current != null;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Private data

        private readonly Stack<BinaryTreeNode> mNodeStack = new Stack<BinaryTreeNode>();

        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't work. You don't just go up if there's no right subtree, because you've already been there. That puts you into an infinite loop.